# Set AutocompleteTextView hint in a single line with Ellipsize end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I want to set the hint of my AutocompleteTextView in a single line with extra string to be truncated with dots(...) in the end.

I am using `singleLine="true"`, `maxLines="1"`, `ellipsize="end"`.

But still the hint is shown in two lines. Although The text is set to single line. But I need the hint should also need to shown in single line.
The Preview in Android Studio shows the hint in single line. But when I run it on Device it shows in 2 lines.(S5, Nexus-5, Nexus-6, J7).

I also want the imeOption should be always search. i.e. `imeOptions="actionSearch"`  Hence I can't change it to actionNext.

Below is my XML Code:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/liLaySearchMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/cococo"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="A Very Long Hint Text Which Need To Be Tuncated At the End In Single Line"
                android:id="@+id/edSearch"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvCancel"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp"
                android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_red"
                android:padding="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Can Anyone Please en-curtain the issue I am facing. As I think I had used every possible solution but still the hint is not in single line.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
[image]

these are screenshots on my Device and xml i tried is as follows

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hint="A Very Long Hint Text Which Need To Be Tuncated At the End In Single Line"
        android:id="@+id/edSearch"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

try Setting `android:inputType="text"` on the `AutoCompleteTextView` it worked for me

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:hint="this is to check if it's getting truncated and in single line or not"/>
```

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela I tried on my system It's perfectly working I really wonder why it's not working in your case. Try clean and build or uninstall app and reinstall in your device

Comment: and on a device and not on a preview screen of the android studio?

Comment: Well What I see is you have all the parameter what I have. Just you have increased the font size. rest all is same. Its Not working on Samsung S5, Samsung J7. Nexus 5, Nexus 6. On Emulator and on Preview screen it works. Please have a look to the question once more.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:inputType="text"` on the `AutoCompleteTextView` it worked for me, unlike `android:ellipsize="end"`, the text did not stay with '...' on end, but it does meet expectations.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```